# TypeError: bookmarks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

**I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to manage the state. I have the following code:**

reducer.js

```
import { actionTypes } from "./actionsTypes";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  bookmarks: [],
  hidden: false,
  basket: [],
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };

    case actionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload,
      };

    case actionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
        items: [],
      };

    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_BOOKMARK:
      return {
        ...state,
        bookmarks: [...state.bookmarks, action.payload],
      };

    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_BASKET:
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [...state.basket, action.payload],
      };

    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        hidden: !state.hidden,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

actions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { actionTypes } from "./actionsTypes";

..
...
...

export const addToBookmarks = (item) => ({
  type: actionTypes.ADD_TO_BOOKMARK,
  payload: item,
});

export const addToBasket = (product) => ({
  type: actionTypes.ADD_TO_BASKET,
  payload: product,
});

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://fakestoreapi.com";

export const fetchProducts = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
    try {
      return axios
        .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/Products")
        .then(({ data }) => dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(data)));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

selectors.js

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

export const selectItems = (state) => state.products; 
export const selectBookmarksProducts = createSelector(
[selectItems],
(shop) => shop.bookmarks
);
```

**For my reducer function, the initial state ( items ) is retrieved data from an api.**

Product.js

```
const Product = ({ product, toggleHidden, addToBookmarks, addToBasket }) => {
  const { title, category, description, image, price } = product || {};    
  return (
    <div className="relative">
     ....
     .....
      <HeartIcon
        className={`absolute top-2 right-4 w-8 cursor-pointer ${
          bookmark ? "text-red-500" : "text-gray-500"
        }`}
        onClick={() => addToBookmarks(product)}
      />
      <CustomButton onClick={() => addToBasket(product)}>
        Add to Basket
      </CustomButton>
    </div>
  );
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addToBookmarks: (item) => dispatch(addToBookmarks(item)),
  toggleHidden: () => dispatch(toggleHidden()),
  addToBasket: (item) => dispatch(addToBasket(item)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Product);
```

Note : I dispatched an action addToBookmarks and I passed product as an object
After that, I want to get the bookmarks products in the bookmarksPage
I don't know why I got this error **TypeError: state.bookmarks is not iterable**
Please can anyone help

Comment: where are you getting this error?

Comment: When I bookmark a product then I visit /bookmarks page I got the error

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider this a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so getting help here might be difficult. For one, the Selectors and the JSX you are providing aren't the most hepful, and you don't show how the reducer is connected to the store (are you using [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)?). I'd try logging `{ state, action }` from that reducer and see when `bookmarks` is changing to a non-array. Alternatively, you could use [redux devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension).

Comment: Did you check in redux store whether the expected value is saved.. you can use redux devtools to see what is the data getting stored in store.

Comment: Everything is fine because I dispatched an async function to fetch products from an API the problem is in the bookmarks state

Answer (score 0):

I believe following change will solve the issue

```
case actionTypes.ADD_TO_BOOKMARK:
{
      const bookmarks = state.bookmarks;
      bookmarks.push(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        bookmarks,
      };
}
```

Comment: products:
  bookmarks: {id: 1, title: "Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops", price: 
  109.95, description: "Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in th…to 15 inches) in 
  the padded sleeve, your everyday", category: "men's clothing", …}
  hidden: false 
  items: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
  {…}, {…}]
  loading: false
This is the productsReducer state I used redux-logger to log each action. I don't understand why bookmarks is an object while Initially, I set it to an empty array.

Comment: I changed the curly braces instead the square bracket I got the same error

Comment: My bad.. i have made edit in the answer... i believe this will solve the issue.. let me know

Comment: The same issue Rabeeh

Comment: try to console.log(bookmarks) after the push method and see what is there?

Comment: Yes I tried that this error throws TypeError: bookmarks.push is not a function

Comment: and what about console(state.bookmarks) before the push method? is not returning empty array?

Comment: I console.log(bookmarks) before the push method and I got a product which is an object

Comment: try to clear the store and do again.. in the first case of adding an item to bookmark, it must return an empty array. otherwise there is some other method which is adding a product to bookmark state which is not shown here in the code

Comment: How can I delete the redux store please ?

Comment: Should I create a new store or what ?

Comment: I got it the problem is here when I deleted the products from whitelist it works 
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["products"], ==> [ ] 
};